# Having a problem in python: Showing error can only concatenate str (not "bool") to str

Tags: python

I am quite new to python, so sorry for the "noob" code if you will say. But please help me :
I am trying to add two numbers and show which one is bigger as a boolean value

```py
num_1 = input("Enter first number: ")    
num_2 = input("Enter second number: ")

num_1 = int(num_1)
num_2 = int(num_2)

Sum = num_1 + num_2

print(Sum)

Greater = num_1 > num_2
Smaller = num_1 < num_2

print("is number 1 greater than number 2?  " + Greater)
print("is number 2 greater than number 1?  " + Smaller)
```

Comment: did u got any errors?

Comment: Try `str(Greater)` in your print statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of a comparison operator is a boolean (either `True` or `False`). As the error message says, you can't concatenate strings with boolean values, as Python is a strongly typed language. You have several options:

1. Pass them as separate arguments to the `print` function:

   ```
   print("is number 1 greater than number 2?", Greater)
   print("is number 2 greater than number 1?", Smaller)
   ```
2. Use an f-string:

   ```
   print(f"is number 1 greater than number 2? {Greater}")
   print(f"is number 2 greater than number 1? {Smaller}")
   ```
3. Use `.format()`:

   ```
   print("is number 1 greater than number 2? {}".format(Greater))
   print("is number 2 greater than number 1? {}".format(Smaller))
   ```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Most of the times i dont even understand what the error is  trying to say.

Comment: @AdityaCodes Happy to help. Paying attention to error message itself is very important and useful. Most of the time it's the best guide.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate string with a bool value after casting it with `str`.

```py
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))

sum = num1 + num2
print(sum)

greater = num1 > num2
smaller = num1 < num2

print("Is number 1 greater than number 2? " + str(greater))

print("Is number 2 greater than number 1? " + str(smaller))
```

See the result [here](https://ideone.com/Q72v4Z).

Comment: No you can NOT concatenate string with a bool value. What you showed here is the concatenation of string with string, not string with bool. You converted that boolean value to string first so it's not a boolean value anymore.

Comment: Sorry. I added _after casting it with `str`_.

Answer (score 0):

Do a string format and that should print true or false

```
print(f"is number 1 greater than number 2? {Greater} " )

print(f"is number 2 greater than number 1? {Smaller}" )
```

output

```
Enter first number: 12
Enter second number: 33
45
is number 1 greater than number 2? False 
is number 2 greater than number 1? True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually concatenate the bool values into the string

```
print("is number 1 greater than number 2? {}".format(Greater))
print("is number 2 greater than number 1? {}".format(Smaller))
```

Or you could convert the bool values into a string

```
print("is number 1 greater than number 2? " + str(greater))
print("is number 2 greater than number 1? " + str(smaller))
```

And here is a better approach

```
num1, num2 = map(int, input().split())
print(max(num1, num2))
```